# Service 'app' failed to build: unauthorized: authentication required while dockerizing a laravel app

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been trying to dockerize my laravel app but I keep getting a `Service 'app' failed to build: unauthorized: authentication required` error every time I run docker-compose build. 
Below are the docker files I used:

docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '2'
services:

  # The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=database"
      - "MYSQL_USER=root"
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

My app.dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
  mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
  && pecl install imagick \
  && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
  && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql
```

The web.dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.10

ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

The vhost.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

The above files are located in the root directory of my laravel app and I use  Windows 10 Pro.
Any help to resolving my issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are mapping your local app directory into your container. On Docker for Windows 10 you must do the following to make the local drive available to your container:

1. Right-click on the Docker tray icon
2. Select "Settings"
3. Select "Shared Drives"
4. Check the box next to the drive your application code resides on.
5. Enter your login credentials when asked.

Note: If you change your login password then you'll need to go back to this settings location and "Reset credentials"